# ActiveAdmin with PaperClip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, activeadmin

I'm trying to use active admin gem with paperclip. I'm new to Ruby and i think this is possible. Please dont vote this question down if I'm wrong.

My active admin's user_benefit file is as follows

```
ActiveAdmin.register UserBenefit do
  menu  priority: 7
  permit_params :available_benefit

  index do
    selectable_column
    default_actions
    column :id
    column :available_benefit
    column :created_at
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "User Benefit Details" do
      f.input :available_benefit
      f.input :benefit_image
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

my model is

```
class UserBenefit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :benefit_image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :benefit_image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

when i'm trying to load the admin's page i'm getting an error..
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Please help

Comment: show the full error..

Comment: Got the answer from Sooraj..

Comment: Good! But always add full stack trace.. At least first 5-6 lines enough, which help to locate error source quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
f.input :benefit_image
```

to

```
f.input :image, :required => false, :as => :file
```